# How to access tabBar click from another viewController

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2, ios5

my home page is a tabbarView,now ,I have a presentModalView Controller,and as we know modalview takes the full screen,now this view has button,on click of which I want to dismiss the modalview and select 2nd tab of my home page so how can i do it.

thanks and Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your TabbarController instance is in appDelegate. When you dismiss the modalView, you post a notification. Your app delegate will be observing this notification and when it receives it, it will call [myTabController setSelectedIndex:2]; Following could be the code:

```
// modalViewController
-(void)dismiss
{
   //your regular code
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"modalDismissed" object:nil];
}
//appDelegate
-(void)applicationDidFinish....
{
  //your regular code
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectAnotherTab)   name:@"modalDismissed" object:nil];
}
-(void)selectAnotherTab
{
   [myTabController setSelectedIndex:2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here u have to use appdelegate class object of tabbarcontroller to chage index or tab
try  following

```
 [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#>];
 or
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>];
```

for example

```
app_appAppDelegate *appdelegate=(app_appAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[appdelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

i have get the rough code may give error so please  check it

**EDIT**

```
 app_appAppDelegate *appdelegate=(app_appAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication]delegate];

[appdelegate.tabBarController  setSelectedViewController:[appdelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtindex:1]];
```

Comment: -(void)menuTab
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
    MenuViewController *menuView =[[MenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:nil];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:menuView];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
}

Comment: but its not working ,m not able to go the view which is on second tab,,so please help me out

Comment: @Ranjit Add  -Edit part of the code before  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];